# simple t-sql: easier solution than triple-join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Based on this table…
[image]

The above is a sample of the table, but is representative, I want to return the next result: (should be grouped by VisId), I need to return: the fist prop11 (based on date_time), the first non-‘root’ prop11 (based on date_time) and the last prop11 (based on date_time).

So for this case I would need to return in one row: ‘Root’, ‘Mkge’, ‘root’. (in one row, 3 columns). How can I achieve that?
(I achieved it with a triple self-join, but I reckon there might be a more performant way).

Comment: Some sample data (as text) and a clearer spec would be needed here. I.e. from the spec you've given, aren't the first and third columns always `Root`? If not, please outline the circumstances (e.g. might the first by `null` if the very first `prop11` value isn't equal to `root`?)

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ As posted this just isn't answerable.

Answer (score 0):

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with multiple [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)s, and conditional aggregation:

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn_asc  = row_number() over (partition by VisId order by date_time asc)
    , rn_desc = row_number() over (partition by VisId order by date_time desc)
    , rn_mkge = case when prop11 <> 'Root' 
                  then row_number() over (partition by VisId order by date_time asc) 
                end
  from t
)
select 
    VisId
  , FirstProp    = max(case when rn_asc  = 1 then date_time end)
  , FirstNonRoot = max(case when rn_mkge = 1 then date_time end)
  , LastProp     = max(case when rn_desc = 1 then date_time end)
from cte
group by VisId
```

without the `cte`:

```
select 
    VisId
  , FirstProp    = max(case when rn_asc  = 1 then date_time end)
  , FirstNonRoot = max(case when rn_mkge = 1 then date_time end)
  , LastProp     = max(case when rn_desc = 1 then date_time end)
from (
  select *
    , rn_asc  = row_number() over (partition by VisId order by date_time asc)
    , rn_desc = row_number() over (partition by VisId order by date_time desc)
    , rn_mkge = case when prop11 <> 'Root' 
                  then row_number() over (partition by VisId order by date_time asc) 
                end
  from t
  ) s
group by VisId
```